# How to escape and print forward slash in Makefile's goals names by regular expression?

Tags: regex, makefile, grep

I do run Makefile with multiple .mk files with many goals, then I try to parse included files to sort and print help details. That works just fine, if regular goal names are used, but I cannot escape slash. I tried to escape it by using `\/`, and other.

Help goal:

```
help: ## Prints commands help
    @grep --no-filename --extended-regexp '^[a-zA-Z_-]+:.*?## .*$$' $(MAKEFILE_LIST) | sort | awk 'BEGIN {FS = ":.*?## "}; {printf "\033[36m%-26s\033[0m %s\n", $$1, $$2}'
```

There is examples of make's goals I'd like to parse to show list of commands on `make help`:

```
docker/ps: ## List docker containers
    @docker ps

docker/machine/ps: ## List containers in docker machine
    @docker-machine ps
```

Slash delimiter can be very helpful on make's autocomplete, if many commands on same sections.

Comment: Maybe there is a language barrier, but your question is unclear. What command do you want to execute, and what do you want Make to print?

Comment: - command `make help` should print the list of commands

Comment: If you will rename goals from docker/ps to docker_ps and docker/machine/ps to docker_machine_ps, then make help prints list of all commands and descriptions starting by ##

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if your targets may contain slashes, don't you just need to adjust the grep command to allow that?  E.g., add it to the character class `[a-zA-Z_-]`?  As it stands that will only match targets containing upper/lowecase letters, underscore, and dash... not slash.

I think your use of `.*?` won't do what you want here... ERE's (extended REs) don't support non-greedy matching as best as I recall.  But it doesn't matter, you don't need this anyway.

Personally I think this is a bit too restrictive since you don't allow whitespace after the target name.  Maybe use something like:

```
grep ... '^ *[-a-zA-Z0-9_/]+ *:.*## ' | sort -u ...
```

Comment: Thank you! 

That sequence is exactly what I need - best self documenting Makefile's help target with multiple includes plus slash option on goals available.